# Getting an arbitrary substring from a port seems impossible in Racket

Tags: port, racket

In Racket, I want to be able to peek anywhere in a port (also before the current position), and read the contents there, without affecting the port in any way. The specified position (`start-pos` in the following code) is supposed to be *from the beginning*, not relative to the current port position!

My first attempt:

```
(define (extract-string port start-pos span)
  (define pos (file-position port))
  (file-position port start-pos)
  (define result (read-string span port))
  (file-position port pos)
  result)

(define port (open-input-string "Hello world"))
(port-count-lines! port)
(port-next-location port)
(extract-string port 0 3)
(port-next-location port)
```

Outputs:

```
1
0
1
"Hel"
1
3
4
```

Somehow the position was not reset by `(file-position port pos)`...

My second attempt:

```
(define (extract-string port start-pos span)
  (define port2 (peeking-input-port port #:init-position start-pos))
  (read-string span port2))

(define port (open-input-string "Hello world"))
(port-count-lines! port)

; port-next-location is not affected; great
(port-next-location port)
(extract-string port 1 3)
(port-next-location port)

; Reading from an earlier point does not work!
(read-string 6 port)
(extract-string port 1 3)
(read-string 5 port)
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
"Hel"
1
0
1
"Hello "
"wor"
"world"
```

Edit: Expected output:

```
1
0
1
"Hel"
1
0
1
"Hello "
"Hel"
"world"
```

A small improvement, but it still does not work as intended.. For some reason, the initial position of `port2` is offset from that of `port`, although the reference says

> The resulting port’s initial position (as reported by file-position)
>   is (- init-position 1), no matter the position of in.

Is it impossible to do this in Racket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit after comments:**

```
(define port (open-input-string "Hello world"))

(define (extract-string-getter my_port)
  (let* ((prev_pos (file-position my_port))
         (new_port (open-input-string (port->string my_port))))
    (file-position my_port prev_pos)
    (lambda (start_pos span)
      (peek-string span start_pos new_port))
    ))

(define runner (extract-string-getter port))
runner
(runner 1 3)
(runner 1 3)
;(runner 5 9)
(port-count-lines! port)
; port-next-location is not affected; great
(port-next-location port)
;(extract-string port 1 3)
(port-next-location port)

; Reading from an earlier point does not work!
(read-string 6 port)
(runner 0 2)
(read-string 5 port)
(runner 6 9)
```

**You still have a scoping issue :) It is very important to know scopes in and out.**

The inner lambda has a state and by saving the reference to it, 'reader', I am able to reuse it's inner objects' states!

**Output:**

```
#<procedure:...\Documents\1.rkt:18:4>
"ell"
"ell"
1
0
1
1
0
1
"Hello "
"He"
"world"
"world"
```

**Important things:**

- It's better to have a different name for the parameter port of *extract-string* than the name of the global parameter port.
- I made a new port in order to not get in the way of original port then read everything and reset file position (though there is a prettier way I'm sure).
- Work with lambdas as objects when you want encapsulation

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have failed to explain clearly enough what I want. I want `(extract-string port start-pos span)` to return the string starting at positiong `start-pos` _from the beginning_ - not affected by where the port is currently located, and not affecting the location of the port. Example: Say I have read 100 characters of a port and call `(extract-string port 50 10)` - this should re-read 10 characters I have already read. I have updated my question with expected output to illustrate.

Comment: Why I want it: I have a lexer which calls arbitrary lexeme-parsing function that simply consume characters of a port until the lexeme is complete. It would be convenient if the lexer also would take care of gathering the characters traversed by the lexeme parser. It would have to: 1) store the initial position 2) call the lexeme parser 3) `extract-string` from the initial position, to the current position. I hope that made sense. Anyway, I do have an (ugly) workaround at the moment...

Comment: @Ploppz You'd like exact-string to be:

exact-string(start_index , end_index) ?

or

exact-string(start_index , num_of_chars) ?

Comment: The latter, `(extract-string start-index num-of-chars)`

Comment: Ok I see your update, and it works as long as the port is initially in position `1`. But I now realize that it should be possible to initialize such a `runner` at the very beginning for use later, at least in my application. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As far as I can see right now, it's not possible to jump _backward_ in position, in a port that has already consumed some characters. Correct? Asking this just out of curiosity.

Comment: also (file-position my_port prev_pos) <- this sets the file position

Comment: Hm yeah that way it's possible. The only problem with file-position is that it doesn't reset the position count you get from `port-count-lines!` - it just keeps counting. As for (runner 6 9) (runner 1 9), I see that's possible but it requires a port at position 1 as a starting point. Anyway, these things are not that important. (edit: it just entails that with this sloution, you will have to pass around a `runner`, as you can't construct one after reading from the port)